# Unexpected Behavior for CompletableFuture.allOf().orTimeout()

Tags: java, asynchronous, timeout, future

There are 2 ways to to force a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to timeout after a given amount of time:

- [`orTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))
- [`get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

I would expect them to behave the same. However, when applied to [`CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)), these 2 ways of providing a timeout behave quite differently !

Basically, it seems that `get()` does what I would expect (it blocks the current thread until all futures have completed), whereas `orTimeout()` seems to behave very strangely (it unblocks the current thread as soon as it can after the first future has completed).

Here's some code to demo the behavior I am observing:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

public class AllOfWithTimeoutTest {

    public static final int TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 100;

    @Test
    public void allOfOrTimeout1() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        getAllOfFuture().get(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void allOfOrTimeout2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        getAllOfFuture().orTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> getAllOfFuture() {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(1)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(2)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(3)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(4)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(5)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(6)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(7)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(8))
        );
    }

    public static void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
            System.out.format("Had a nap for %s milliseconds.\r\n", millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

The printout of `allOfOrTimeout1()` is what I would expect:

```
Had a nap for 1 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 2 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 3 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 4 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 5 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 6 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 7 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 8 milliseconds.
```

The printout of `allOfOrTimeout2()` is NOT what I would expect, and varies slightly at every execution. It typically prints out between the first 2 and 5 lines, but never 8. Here's a version where it printed out only 2 lines:

```
Had a nap for 1 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 2 milliseconds.
```

Also, if I run the whole test in IntelliJ, I get some extra lines at the end:

```
Had a nap for 1 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 2 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 3 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 4 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 5 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 6 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 7 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 8 milliseconds.



Had a nap for 1 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 2 milliseconds.

Had a nap for 3 milliseconds.
Had a nap for 4 milliseconds.

Process finished with exit code 0
Had a nap for
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the expected behavior for `orTimeout()` ?
2. If not, why is it doing this ?

Comment: You can add `Thread.sleep()` before the end of method `allOfOrTimeout2` and you should see rest of messages.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review below answers ? Thanks

Comment: did you got your answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the expected behavior for orTimeout() ?

Yes.

`OrTimeout` is a non blocking async call whereas `get` is a blocking async call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected behavior.

I think the key thing to realize first is that `async` methods in the `CompletableFuture` would run the task by default on the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()), where all threads are set as [*daemon* threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon()), meaning that the JVM would not wait until it is finished to exit. A note in the Javadocs of [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) mentions this: *"All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool()"*

With this in mind, the `orTimeout()` makes the current `CompletableFuture` (which is the combination of all 8 `CompletableFuture` tasks) complete with an exception if it has not completed normally within the given timeout. Unlike `get()`, this does not block the current thread, but simply adds a timeout to the `CompletableFuture` returned by `getAllOfFuture()`. After `orTimeout()` is called, the current thread continues, and since there is nothing left to do, the JVM finishes before all the tasks have had the chance to run because they are being executed by daemon threads.

As for the reason why only a few tasks get to finish, I suspect it is because of the JUnit test post-processing phase, i.e. after the test method is finished, the main thread still has to run some JUnit post-processing code, which gives time for some of the worker threads to finish their tasks. If you run the code in a normal main method (outside JUnit), the `orTimeout` example would probably not even a single task output, because the thread immediately finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you write it like this:

```
public static void allOfOrTimeout2() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = getAllOfFutures();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.orTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS);
}
```

and put yourself in the shoes of the `main` thread and think how it is supposed to execute `allOfOrTimeout2()`, things will be easier.

`main` thread needs to execute `allOfOrTimeout2`. It goes into this method and returns from there a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. Does it wait for it to complete? Nope. Even the documentation says that, if you *want* to wait for this `CompletableFuture` to finish, you need to:

> Among the applications of this method is to await completion of a set of independent CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in: CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2,c3).join();

But you do not call that `join`, you return it from the method and move on.

The execution of that `CompletableFuture` though, does start. It executes in threads from `ForkJoinPool`, via those `runAsync` (this is how `supplyAsync` for example works too: you dispatch to a different thread the actual work, and the thread that invoked `supplyAsync` moves on).

`main` thread then moves on to this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.orTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS);
```

It needs to call `orTimeout` and the documentation says:

> Exceptionally completes this CompletableFuture with TimeoutException **if not otherwise completed** before the given timeout.

Is the `future1` completed? This is again a timing issue, but most probably no (for it to be completed all those `runAsync` need to finish). So there is no timeout and the invocation of `allOfOrTimeout2` is over.

Now those threads that run the code in `runAsync` are called daemon threads, a VM does not have to wait for them to be over in order to shut down. So `main` thread is over, those threads are not stopping the VM, so everything ends.

Since the entire output depends on how threads are getting scheduled, it is impossible to predict it. You can't even predict if `future2` finishes before VM shuts down.

---

Of course if you want predictable result: you either wait for `future2` to be done or pass an executor to `runAsync`.

Comment: as per your last statement ```you either wait for future2 to be done or pass an executor to runAsync.```, if I am using executor service, I will need to call ```shutdownNow``` on it right ? like ```getAllOfFuture().orTimeout(timeOut, millisec).whenComplete((v,ex)-> //here if ex != null, call shutDownNow);```